# ExpressJS & Passport pass req, res

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to pass req & res through to the callback to check the user's ip using a requestIp to prevent multi accounting, any help would be very appreciated. (req.clientIp returns the user's ip)

users.js file snippit:

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ['profile', 'email']
}));
router.get('/google/callback', (req, res) => {
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    failureRedirect: '/users/register'
  }), (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  };
});
```

passport.js file snippit:

```
  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: keys.googleClientId,
    clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/users/google/callback',
    proxy: true
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log(accessToken, profile);

    // const image = profile.photos[0].value;
    const email = profile.emails[0].value;
    var google = {
      googleID: profile.id,
      firstName: profile.name.givenName,
      lastName: profile.name.familyName,
      image: profile.photos[0].value
    }
    console.log(google);

    User.findOne({
      email: email
    }).then(user => {
      if (user) {
        user.google = google
        user.save().then(() => {
          done(null, user);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('no user');
        new User({
          email: email,
          username: `${google.firstName} ${google.lastName}`,
          google: google
        }).save().then(user => {
          done(null, user);
        });
      };
    });
  }));
```

Edit: I want to access req & res in the passport.js file. Other than that everything does work

If you need more information I will provide it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in router.get('/google'...
You **must** send something back to the client.

```js
router.get('/google', function(req,res){
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
  });
  res.send('something');
});
router.get('/google/callback', (req, res) => {
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    failureRedirect: '/users/register'
  }), (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');//as these you send something
  };
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific, I wanted to access req & res in the passport.js file. Other than that it does work as it should

Answer (score 0):

You can get the request object passed to your verify callback with the  `passReqToCallback` option. The verify callback will have the request object as the first argument and the rest follows as normal. Like this

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  // ...
  passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  // access to req
})
```

Also, remember to fix the `'/google/callback'` route setup. There's at least one ending brace missing. And you're not having the function returned by `authenticate()` being actually called (it should have the form of `authenticate()()` in an anonymous function).